platform_get_resource() with IORESOURCE_IRQ returning NULLl and platform_device .id is -1
I'm running into difficulty binding a GPIO trigger device on Raspberry Pi. I've added some print statements to the probe function for debugging.
The first thing I'm seeing is that the call to platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_IRQ, 0) is returning NULL. Looking further upstream, I'm seeing the pdev->id is returning -1. I'm not sure if that is exepected in this situation but seems suspicious.
The snippet of relevant code from the probe function is as follows:
static int iio_interrupt_trigger_probe(struct platform_device *pdev)
{
    struct iio_interrupt_trigger_info *trig_info;
    struct iio_trigger *trig;
    unsigned long irqflags;
    struct resource *irq_res;
    int irq, ret = 0;

    pr_info("in iio_interrupt_trigger_probe()\n");
    pr_info("name: %s\n", pdev->name);
    pr_info("id: 0x%8x\n", pdev->id);
    pr_info("num resources: %ld\n", pdev->num_resources);

    irq_res = platform_get_resource(pdev, IORESOURCE_IRQ, 0);
    pr_info("platform_get_resource returned: %lu\n", irq_res);

    if (irq_res == NULL)
        return -ENODEV;

The device tree overlay I'm using to register the device is as follows:
/dts-v1/;
/plugin/;

/ {
    fragment@0 {
      target = <&soc>;
      __overlay__ {
        /* ----------- GPIO 20 Rising Edge Trigger ------------ */
        gpiotrig {
           compatible = "my,iio-trig-interrupt";
           interrupt-parent = <&gpio>;
           interrupts = <20 1>;
        };
      };
    };
};

The resulting dmesg logs are:
[12647.977018] in iio_interrupt_trigger_probe()
[12647.977064] name: soc:gpiotrig
[12647.977081] id: 0xffffffff
[12647.977098] num resources: 0
[12647.977113] platform_get_resource returned: 0

Any pointers to help me troubleshoot and resolve this is appreciated.

What is the parent node of your device supposed to be? Looks like you've placed your device node as a direct child of root. Check /proc/device-tree/ on the running system.

It is placed under /proc/device-tree/soc/gpiotrig as per the target clause in the overlay.
I must be missing something in the .dts for the platform_get_resource() call to return the IRQ information.

"I must be missing something in the .dts for the platform_get_resource() call to return the IRQ information." - Yes, such as the appropriate  parent for your node. No way that soc is the correct parent, i.e. at the same or higher level as the interrupt and pin/gpio controllers..

ok, so maybe I need to choose a different placement subtending off of the gpio controller perhaps? I'll take another look at the DT and see what other options there are. If you have any suggestions on where it should be placed that would be great too.

So far the behavior is the same with the trigger device placed here:
raspberrypi:/proc/device-tree/soc/gpio@7e200000/gpiotrig $ ls
compatible  interrupt-parent  interrupts  name

pdev->id == -1 is fine. You should use irq = platform_get_irq(); if (irq < 0) return irq; instead of open coding it. Most likely you will get -ENXIO which means that driver can't find interrupt, which means your DTS is broken for this.
